# Unhandled rejection CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ email: 'test@g mail.com' }" at path "email" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, mongoose, redux

what does this error meant for I was trying to make resetPasswordRequest , but whenever i try to submit email to get reset link on mailtrap.io spinner keeps on loading and this error appears at the terminal.

```
Unhandled rejection CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ email: 'test@g
mail.com' }" at path "email" for model "User"
    at new CastError (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\mongoose\li
b\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at SchemaString.cast (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\mongoos
e\lib\schema\string.js:476:9)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType._castForQuery (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\
node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1088:15)
    at SchemaString.castForQuery (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules
\mongoose\lib\schema\string.js:531:15)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\projects\bookworm\bookwor
m-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1045:15)
    at cast (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js
:214:34)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\mo
ngoose\lib\query.js:3305:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node
_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1295:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_module
s\mongoose\lib\query.js:1507:8)
    at C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:250:8
    at C:\projects\bookworm\bookworm-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

these are my files

> router/auth.js

```
router.post('/reset_password_request', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      sendResetPasswordEmail(user);
      res.json({});
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ errors: { global: 'There user with such email' } })
    }
  });
});
```

> model/User.js

```
schema.methods.generateResetPasswordToken = function generateResetPasswordToken() {
  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id
  }, process.env.KEY,
  { expiresIn: '1s' });
}

schema.methods.generateResetPasswordLink = function generateResetPasswordLink() {
  return `${process.env.HOST}/reset_password/${this.generateResetPasswordToken()}`
}
```

Comment: Can you console.log and check what you are getting in req.body.email

Comment: pending request and same loading spinner.

Comment: Can you put a console log in router/auth.js before User.findOne

Comment: did you mean like this         router.post('/reset_password_request', (req, res) => {
  console.log({ email: req.body.email });

Comment: console.log (req.body.email)

Comment: i think this is working fine as this gives { email: 'test@gmail.com' }

Comment: User.findOne (req.body.email). Use this...it should work

Comment: yeah it's working now but can you please tell me why it is not working in this case User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

Comment: Because req.body.email already contains the query object.

Comment: oh thank you so much